# Python - Slack outgoing webhook to Telegram

Tags: python, flask, telegram, slack

I'm working on a webhook that sends Telegrams messages to Slack and Slack messages to Telegram; right now I can send Telegram messages to Slack but I can't send from Slack to Telegram because I don't know how to get the data. As the Slack documentation states, the data sent on the POST request is like this:

```
token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
team_id=T0001
team_domain=example
channel_id=C2147483705
channel_name=test
timestamp=1355517523.000005
user_id=U2147483697
user_name=Steve
text=googlebot: What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?
trigger_word=googlebot:
```

The content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

From that data I want to get the `user_name` and `text`

On my Flask code I don't have nothing because I don't know how to receive that data or how can I see it on the console so I could try to extract it and send it to Telegram, this is the only thing that I have for the Slack webhook just because I wanted to see if it was working, I think that these lines of code are not relevant right now:

```
@app.route("/" + SLACK, methods=['POST'])
def slack_handler():
    if request.method == "POST":
        return "POST"
```

And that's my problem; how can I receive, store that data? if I should explain more my issue please let me know and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your slack webhook is configured appropriately you should be able to treat it like a form. The following should work-

```
from flask import Flask, request

slack_webhook = your_webhook_here
@app.route('/slack', methods=['POST'])
def slack():
    if request.form.get('token') == slack_webhook:
         channel = request.form.get('channel')
         username = request.form.get('username')
         return "Channel: " + channel + "Username: " + username
    else:
       return "None found"
```

Read this post for more on this-
[realpython.com](https://realpython.com/blog/python/getting-started-with-the-slack-api-using-python-and-flask/#receiving-messages)

Comment: Hello, I tried doing it like this but I'm not getting anything from it; I mean, from the link that you posted I followed some things and downloaded ngrok and I'm indeed getting the POST requests but I can't get the data, I tried printing it to the console but it's not printing anything while in the ngrok inspect page I can see the requests and body of each, do you know what may be happening?

Comment: Nevermind! It was being confused by the Telegram request somehow, it's working now, thanks!